# Can't acess windows files and folders after delete crash report[dual-boot 7 & 14.04]

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7, filesystem

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 successfully. And I did access windows files and flowers from Ubuntu(i.e I can see every drives from 14.04).

Few days ago I got problem that is when I start my system I will get a popup message with `Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced internal error` every time. So that I have removed "crashed report" by typing following command in terminal.

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

After that when I open 'Files' I can only see 'computer' other drives which present in windows are not showing.

How I will access again that the other drivers which present in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it back when I command the following in terminal,

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and restarted[`sudo reboot`].

Now I can access every drives which present in windows 7.